# C++ vector issues

Tags: c++, vector

My application keeps crashing on me for whatever reason. I am new to vectors so there is more than likely something silly on my part.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>    

using namespace std;

class Projectile
{
private:
    SDL_Surface *projectile;
    void load();

public:
    int count;

    vector< int > c;
    vector< vector< int > > p;

    int positionX;
    int positionY;

    Projectile();
    void newProjectile( int, int );
    void drawCurrentState( SDL_Surface* );
};

...
...

void Projectile::newProjectile( int x, int y )
{
    positionX = x;
    positionY = y;

    c.push_back( 10 );
    c.push_back( 10 );

    //p.push_back( c ); //trying to start off simple before i do multidimensional.
}

void Projectile::drawCurrentState( SDL_Surface* destination )
{   
    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = c[0]; //will eventually me the multidimensional p vector
    offset.y = c[1]; //

    SDL_BlitSurface( projectile, NULL, destination, &offset );
}
```

what exactly am I doing wrong here? I push back two values ( will be the x and y ints after done testing ) however it seems to crash when it gets to the `offset.x = c[0];` part of the script.

I thought for certain both c[0] and c[1] should be equal to 10. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you call `drawCurrentState` before `newProjectile`? Insert a `std::cout << c.size() << std::endl;` before the assignment to `offset.x`.

Comment: we can't see that from the code shown. My guess is you work on different instances of `Projectile` (also, if the copy constructor - not shown) is incomplete, this would lead to empty `c` vector after copy... Long shot

Comment: How do you call the newProjectile and drawCurrentState funtions? Are you sure is there something inside c vector?

Comment: Maybe using `vector::at` instead of `vector::operator[]` gives hints. It will throw an `out_of_range` exception if subscript is not valid

Comment: The word "eventually" is somewhat suspicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, both [0] and [1] should be 10.

Just make sure you really call newProjectile() first, and make sure there are no other problems such as invalid destination pointer and so on.

Comment: Ah, yes, it looks like there was a condition causing it to fire beforehand in the main loop. Thanks!

Comment: @Headspin: Note that this demonstrates your design is not robust. It was very easy for you to break it such that you caused _undefined behaviour_, and you were **lucky** that it happened to give you a crash before your code went into production. Instead, consider implementing bounds checking so that you can catch this sort of thing, or shuffle around your functions so that one does not rely on the other having been called beforehand.

Comment: To be honest, it was just old code I forgot to delete. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 2):

The code seems to be okay, but the order of the calls is important. Make sure that you call newProjectile() before you call drawCurrentState(), for example like this:

```
Projectile * projectile = new Projectile();
projectile->newProjectile(1,1);
projectile->drawCurrentState( ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe vector c is empty at line where c[0] is read. Check the result of c.size().